# testing contribution pages

Tags: contribution-page

I need to test some contribution pages before they go live. Is there standard data or a procedure I use?  Specifically I need to verify that the donor receives an email confirmation of whatever type of contribution they made.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is - go to Manage Contribution Pages and search for your page.  On the right hand side next to the page you want to test, click "Links", then "Test Drive".  You can also see this link at the top of the page when editing your contribution page.

For credit card transactions, use Test Visa Card number 4444333322221111, expiry date anything in the future, CVV any three digit number.  NEVER USE REAL CREDIT CARD NUMBERS FOR TEST TRANSACTIONS!

You will get a test receipt as long as you've set the email address to yourself!

No transaction will be made.  You will only be able to find the contribution inside Civi by specifically searching for test contributions.

This works for donations as well as memberships.  It's very useful.  I always test every page before making it live!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to doing the test drive, it is worthwhile doing a live transaction, particularly if you've not tested any contribution pages.

In the past I've done the following:

- Enable pay later, if that is not an option, and test using that.
- Use a CiviDiscount code that makes the charge very small, say $1. If you're not using CiviDiscount, you can always reverse the charge.